# Reordering indices of MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe that summarizes the frequency of responses to four questions in two groups:

```
>>> CrossTab
                      Group A  Group B
FavColor  Green             1        1
          Orange            2        3
          Purple            1        0
FavSport  Baseball          1        2
          Basketball        1        0
          Football          2        2
OtherVar  No                1        1
          Unsure            0        2
          Yes               3        1
OtherVar2 No                4        2
          Yes               0        2
>>>
```

I am looking to reorder the index variables within the both levels of the index. Let's say I want the colors sorted [Green, Purple, Orange], the sports sorted [Football, Baseball, Basketball], and Yes/No questions sorted [Yes, No, Unsure].

And then I would also like the questions sorted in the order [FavSport, FavColor, OtherVar, OtherVar2]:

The dataframe would then look like this:

```
>>> CrossTab2 
                      Group A  Group B
FavSport  Football          2        2
          Baseball          1        2
          Basketball        1        0
FavColor  Green             1        1
          Purple            1        0
          Orange            2        3
OtherVar  Yes               3        1
          No                1        1
          Unsure            0        2
OtherVar2 Yes               0        2
          No                4        2
>>>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to specify the order manually somehow if sit's not a rule-based order.  You say "sorted", but the way you put it, they're not in alphabetical order, just some arbitrary order.

Comment: @BrenBarn, yes I know I'll have to specify the order manually, I'm just wondering how to apply those specified orders. In reality my dataset is much larger and has several 'questions' with the same set of responses. For example many Questions that can be ("Yes","No","Unsure"), many questions that can be ("Not at all", "A Little", "A Lot"), etc. I'd like to specify the orders of these responses and then have them applied to the appropriate questions (level 0 in the index). Does this make sense?

Comment: You could turn it into a category and then back into an index. You can specify custom sorting order in categories.